# Dropdownlist in mvc with bootstrap theme

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a Dropdownlist that contains fields from the model that i have created

as below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedFieldId", new SelectList(Model.Fields, "FieldID","NiceName", Model.SelectedFieldId), new { @class = "dropdown", role = "menu",datatoggle = "dropdown" })
```

this takes default theme of mvc4, but i want to use bootstrap theme. 
I have included all bootstrap files in bundles 
and everything is fine except i dont know how to make this type of dropdown show in bootstrap theme.
 Any help will be much appreciated thank you so much for your time.

Comment: can you provide a link or picture of what you are looking for? along with your *cshtml*?

Comment: Try `@class = "form-control"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList
    ("SelectedFieldId", new SelectList(Model.Fields, "FieldID","NiceName",
  Model.SelectedFieldId),
 new { @class = "form-control", role = "menu",datatoggle = "dropdown" })
```

Comment: how can i have a default label in the dropdownlist currently it showing none

Comment: check this is one @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
              new SelectListItem{ Text="Male",Value="1"},
              new SelectListItem{ Text="Female",Value="2"}
           }, "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control", role = "menu",datatoggle = "dropdown" })

Comment: As a side note, the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor (`Model.SelectedFieldId`) is pointless and can be deleted. Its ignored by the HtmlHelper because its the value of the property that determines what is selected.